# why ist the value printed ist "None" , even though in backgroud the reverse funtion worked properly [python] [thanks]?

Tags: python

why ist the value printed ist "None" , even though in backgroud the reverse funtion worked properly [python] [thanks]?

code:

```
aList = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

print(aList)

['g', 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']

print(aList.reverse())

None
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images. We can't run an image.

Comment: ok, i edit my post, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, `list.reverse()` doesn't return anything - it simply reverses the list (as in, it modifies the actual list). To see the reversed list, either look at `list` after running `list.reverse()`, or use `reversed(list)` to see the reversed list without actually reversing it.